# Firebase Auth : During Auth not getting email from FirebaseUser

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have implemented Firebase Auth using Google in my Android app. When I try to log in using that I am getting `null` as an email from `FirebaseUser` class:

```
    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                        val user = auth.currentUser

                      if(user.email != null) {
                        sendUserDetailToServer()
                        updateUI(user)
                      }

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                        updateUI(null)
                    }
                }
    }
```

I am able to get other details like name, uid etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store it in database firebase auth not return but you can use admin sdk for this

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the Gmail address that is corresponding to the authenticated user, you need to get it from the authResult and **not** from the FirebaseUser object, as it not yet updated. So instead of the following line of code:

```
val user = auth.currentUser
```

Please use:

```
val email = task.result?.user?.email
```

Comment: Hi NarenderNishad! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?